# Making GET request within JSX.element function react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently working on an expo and react-native application and I'm attempting to get some JSON with a latitude and longitude and displaying it as a map marker.

I know there is a lot wrong with the following but I'm struggling greatly to find any documentation for creating GET requests and modifying the information inside of a JSX.element function. Outside of this I'm also not sure how to repeatedly fetch every few minutes in order to continually update this component state

I am sorry if this is basic I am very new to react native and these JSX.element functions not being classes is confusing.

```
export const Map = (): JSX.Element => (
  state = {
    responseData: []
  }
  fetch('https://apiURL', {method: 'GET'})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({responseJson})
    console.log(responseJson)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
    <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        region={{
            latitude: 37.956290,
            longitude: -91.779460,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121
        }}
    >
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: responseData.latitude,
          longitude: responseData.longitude
        }}
        title={"Location"}
        description={"Location of Location"}
      />
    </MapView>
);
```

I use this Map component within another JSX.element component:

```
export const MapScreen = (): JSX.Element => (
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{top: 'always'}}>
      <Map/>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```

Comment: Function-based components (which I think is what you mean by "JSX.element function") don't have a `this.useState`. You need to use _hooks_, read e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

Comment: So I can stick the JSX elements inside of a return statement and the function should work fine?

Comment: No, that's neither what I said nor what the docs show. You do need to return the element, but that's not sufficient to fix what you've posted. You should also read up on the basic arrow function syntax, the second is fine but the first is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to remove the JSX.Element statement from the function, and fetch the data from another function.

```
const useFetch = url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function fetchData(){
    const response = await(fetch(url))
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()

    const interval=setInterval(() => {
      fetchData()
    }, 6000)

    return()=>clearInterval(interval)
  },[url]);

  return data
};
```

```
export const Map = () => {
  const data = useFetch('APIURL')

  if(!data){
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>
  }

  else {
  return(
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      loadingEnabled={true}
      region={{
          latitude: 37.956290,
          longitude: -91.779460,
          latitudeDelta: 0.015,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121
      }}
    >
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: data.latitude,
          longitude: data.longitude
        }}
        title={"title"}
        description={"desc"}
      />
    );
  }
}
```